# how to create a vertical menu bar with drop down items in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create a vertical menu bar with drop down items?
I have created a vertical menu using buttons and placed them into a panel   and assigning the panel's dock property to left, but couldn't find a way to   add drop down items to each button.

Can someone help  how to create  dropdown items?

[image: example is shown in the image]

Comment: no..... a vertical menu bar with drop down items @plutonix

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Like this? You can find MenuStrip Tool in Toolbox. Add it to the form. Right-click and select `Edit Items...`. You can add `MenuItem` (Menu1 in my example), and add SubMenus from Menu1 Property's `DropDownItems`.

Comment: thats not what i meant @eirishainjel